# Why won't this google chart graph this function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a linear function `competitorCost(time)` that I want graphed on a google charts. I have it take in some data using a form and uses this data to create the linear function. However it will not graph.

```
var upfront; 
var monthlyrate;
var wifi;
var firewall;
var backup;
var vpn; 
var install; 
var result;

var competitorCost = function(time){
    return upfront + (time * monthlyrate);
};

var ourCost = function(time){
    return 1000 + (time * 50); 
};

$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#submit').click(function(){ 
        wifi = $('input[name=wifiPrice]').val(); 
        firewall = $('input[name=firewallPrice]').val(); 
        backup = $('input[name=backupPrice]').val(); 
        vpn = $('input[name=vpnPrice]').val(); 
        install = $('input[name=installPrice]').val(); 
        cloudbackup = $('input[name=cloudbackuprate]').val(); 
        support = $('input[name=supportrate]').val(); 

        upfront = parseInt(wifi) + parseInt(firewall) + parseInt(backup) + parseInt(vpn) + parseInt(install); 
        monthlyrate = parseInt(cloudbackup) + parseInt(support); 
    });
}); 

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'Entreda', 'Competitors'],
        ['0', ourCost(0), competitorCost(0)],
        ['6', ourCost(6), competitorCost(6)],
        ['12', ourCost(12), competitorCost(12)],
        ['18', ourCost(18), competitorCost(18)],
        ['24', ourCost(24), competitorCost(24)]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Entreda vs Competitor Costs Over Time',
        width: 480,
        height: 270,
        pointSize: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

`competitorCost(time)` does not graph, however `ourCost(time)` does graph. If i give `upfront` and `monthlyrate` values when i instantiate them, the function graphs just fine, so theres a problem with `upfront` and `monthlyrate` being used in the function. Anyone see my mistake?

update: I just realized that the google chart draws itself as soon as the page loads, so `upfront` and `monthlyrate` are undefined when the graph is drawn. Anyone have suggestions as to how I can get around this? I was thinking of having the chart draw itself after the submit button is pressed, but how could I do that?

Comment: Remove `setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)` and call `drawChart()` when submit is clicked instead...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.Add a button which calls the `loadChart()` like this.

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="loadChart()">
```

The `loadChart()` is

```
function loadChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'Entreda', 'Competitors'],
        ['0', ourCost(0), competitorCost(0)],
        ['6', ourCost(6), competitorCost(6)],
        ['12', ourCost(12), competitorCost(12)],
        ['18', ourCost(18), competitorCost(18)],
        ['24', ourCost(24), competitorCost(24)]
    ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Entreda vs Competitor Costs Over Time',
            width: 480,
            height: 270,
            pointSize: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

This will load the google chart after the button is clicked.

For more google chart related queries take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/)